# How can I Add Request Approval with postman

Tags: request, postman, http-post

I need to do the following steps, but I have not used post request before and I keep getting an error, can you help?

1. Detail of the request
2. API link where they can view the request's validators
3. Confirming the request via api

This is my request:

```json
{
    "approval": {
        "approver": {
            "email_id": "xyz@zmail.com"
        },
        "comments": "Comments for why this entity is approved/rejected",
        "original_approver": {
            "email_id": "xyz@zmail.com"
        },
        "xpath": {
            "display_name": "General Manager",
            "path": "orgroles.udf_ref6"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the response I get:

```json
{
    "response_status": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "field": "input_data",
                "message": "Value not provided",
                "status_code": 4001,
                "type": "failed"
            }
        ],
        "status": "failed",
        "status_code": 4000
    }
}
```

[related photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KYui.png)

I read the documents and tried everything that is written there, but I am missing something, my aim is to do all 3 tasks.

Comment: Please add your request and the response as text instead of a picture.

Comment: [object Object]

{
  "approval": {
    "approver": {
        "email_id": "lincoln@zmail.com"
    },
    "xpath": {
      "path": "orgroles.udf_ref6",
      "display_name": "General Manager"
    },
    "comments": "Comments for why this entity is approved/rejected",
    "original_approver": {
      "email_id": "lincoln@zmail.com"
    }
  }
}

Comment: {
    "response_status": {
        "status_code": 4000,
        "messages": [
            {
                "status_code": 4001,
                "field": "input_data",
                "type": "failed",
                "message": "Value not provided"
            }
        ],
        "status": "failed"
    }
}

Comment: Do you have a link to the API documentation?

Comment: https://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/sdpod-v3-api/requests/request.html

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the API is expecting a value for a field called `input_data`. I'm not entirely sure about the request format required by the API, but you could try adding your request as the value of `input_data`:

```json
{
    "input_data": {
        "approval": {
            "approver": {
                "email_id": "lincoln@zmail.com"
            },
            "comments": "Comments for why this entity is approved/rejected",
            "original_approver": {
                "email_id": "lincoln@zmail.com"
            },
            "xpath": {
                "display_name": "General Manager",
                "path": "orgroles.udf_ref6"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same Problem :(
{
    "response_status": {
        "status_code": 4000,
        "messages": [
            {
                "status_code": 4001,
                "field": "input_data",
                "type": "failed",
                "message": "Value not provided"
            }
        ],
        "status": "failed"
    }
}

Comment: Are you using postman to send your request or something else (e.g. powershell/curl/python...)? Have you set all the headers correctly?

Comment: Yes I did, actually I have not used postman before, I am a python developer, I did this in 5 minutes in python, but the customer insists that he is postman.